# How to display image in Android's TextView?

Tags: android

I want to inset some images in the TextView. How to do it? Any idea

Comment: See this article on how to [set compound drawables to a TextView](http://mgmblog.com/2010/06/04/setcompounddrawable-to-add-drawables-to-textview/)

Comment: using first two answers, you aren't able to add images between text, only on top, bottom, left or right, but my solution allows you to add image at what index you want in the text

Comment: Updated answer by 'Dawid', quite compact.

Answer (score 73, accepted):

You can create a spannableString and place your image where you want in the TextView. Or you can use

```
ImageSpan is = new ImageSpan(context, resId);
text.setSpan(is, index, index + strLength, 0);
```

Comment: won't this end up on an index out of bounds exception because the 3rd parameter, which is int end, is beyond length of the string?

Comment: @LeiLeyba correct. the real answer would be: final Spannable text = new SpannableString(string + " "); text.setSpan(is, string.length(), 1 + string.length(), 0); . this will add an image to the end of the given string.

Comment: If u like to place an image wrapped with text, be aware that its not displayed if u span a "space"-character and the textview inserts a linebreak at that position. I guess the textview cuts all spaces in this case, which leads to the image not beeing displayed at that position. Use a dummy character like "x" which is not cut by the textview instead.

Comment: What if the user was say writing into an EditText box and wanted to add a picture also inside. Let's say it was a note taking app and they wanted to add a picture to those notes? Same process?

Comment: Here "text" is SpannableString

Comment: @BudaGavril Can we use the device stored image with Textview like IMAGE..123456789..IMAGE.. please help me on it

Answer (score 62):

Much easier you can use [SpannableStringBuilder](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/SpannableStringBuilder.html) from API 1

Example usage:

For **API >= 21**

```
    SpannableStringBuilder builder = new SpannableStringBuilder();
    builder.append("My string. I ")
            .append(" ", new ImageSpan(getActivity(), R.drawable.ic_action_heart), 0)
            .append(" Cree by Dexode");

    textView.setText(builder);
```

For **API >= 1**

```
    SpannableStringBuilder builder = new SpannableStringBuilder();
    builder.append("My string. I ").append(" ");
    builder.setSpan(new ImageSpan(getActivity(), R.drawable.ic_action_heart),
            builder.length() - 1, builder.length(), 0);
    builder.append(" Cree by Dexode");

    textView.setText(builder);
```

Comment: Hey, Is it possible by anyway to add an edittext within textview as we have added image within textview like above?

Comment: @Anu You must try :) But probably answer will be YES. Checkout emojis in edit text :)

Comment: This looks interesting: https://github.com/hitanshu-dhawan/SpannableStringParser

Answer (score 25):

```
ImageSpan is = new ImageSpan(context, R.drawable.arrow);
SpannableString text = new SpannableString("Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet");
text.setSpan(is, 5, 5 + 10, 0);
```

Answer (score 11):

do something like this.

```
textView.setCompoundDrawableWithIntrinsicBounds(yourImg, null, null, null);
```

Answer (score 1):

make custom.xml

```
       <RelativeLayout
           xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
           android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content">
          <ImageView 
               android:id="@+id/thumbnail_view"
               android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
               android:layout_width="wrap_content"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <TextView android:id="@+id/message_view"
               android:layout_width="wrap_content"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:layout_toRightOf="@id/thumbnail_view"
               android:textSize="18sp"
               android:text="MyText" />
      </RelativeLayout>
```

then in main.xml , include this custom.xml

```
       <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:orientation="vertical" 
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="fill_parent"  
          android:gravity="center_horizontal">

   <include 
        android:id="@+id/customView"
         layout="@layout/custom"/>

           </LinearLayout>
```

This is my mainActivity.class

```
  package com.example.test;


 import android.app.Activity;
 import android.os.Bundle;
 import android.view.View;
 import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
 import android.widget.ImageView;
  import android.widget.TextView;


     public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

   private String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();
  ImageView img;
  ImageView img1;
  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    TextView txt = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.message_view);
     img = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.thumbnail_view);
     img1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.thumbnail_view1);

    img.setOnClickListener(this);
    img1.setOnClickListener(this);

}
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    if(v== img){
        // do something for img
    }
    else if (v== img1){
        //do something for img1
    }

}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add the image end of the view you can follow me

```
  ImageSpan is = new ImageSpan(context, R.drawable.arrow);
  SpannableString text = new SpannableString("Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet"+"  ");
  text.setSpan(is, text.length()-2, text.length(), 0);
```

if Image need to center alignment you can follow

[ImageSpan center vertical](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28422921/4549220)

recommended @amy answer

Answer (score 0):

here is a View I did precisely for inline images in TextView which also supports click handling on the image
https://github.com/myDario/DarioInlineImageTextView