# Display image with img html in textview

Tags: java, android, html

I wan to display an image in textview. I have an image in res/drawable/img.png
Here is my code:

```
String img="<img src='file:///res/drawable/img.png' />";
txt_html.append(Html.fromHtml(img));
```

But it's not work.

Any idea?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2865452/is-it-possible-to-display-inline-images-from-html-in-an-android-textview

Comment: Duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5561981/how-to-display-image-in-androids-textview

Comment: @Chris: Thank for link, I'll read it

Comment: @SystemParadox: Your link not work :|
I read all the topic you guys give, but It seen too hard to solve problem

Comment: @HanTran: if you're finding it difficult getting your head around the two solutions given above, you might want to try using a WebView instead of a TextView.

Answer (score 4):

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.Html;
import android.text.Html.ImageGetter;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class TextImageActivity extends Activity {
    int imageNumber = 1; //int to check which image is displayed
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    TextView tvText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text);
    final String testContent = "<html><body><b>Test</b><i>Italic</i><br/>"
        + "<img src=\"icon.png\"/>This is like testing if this thing works" + "<img src=\"a.png\"/>" +
                " in a more elaborate</body></html>";
    tvText.setText(Html.fromHtml(testContent, imgGetter, null));
}

  private ImageGetter imgGetter = new ImageGetter() {

    public Drawable getDrawable(String source) {
        Drawable drawable = null;
        if(imageNumber == 1) {
        drawable = getResources().getDrawable(R.raw.icon);
        ++imageNumber;
        } else drawable = getResources().getDrawable(R.raw.a);
        drawable.setBounds(0, 0, drawable.getIntrinsicWidth(), drawable
                                .getIntrinsicHeight());

        return drawable;
    }
 };

 }
```

Comment: Adding explanation to your code helps people learn how to do it on their own.

Answer (score 3):

## To download images from the web and displaying in textView I used this:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

public String htmlContent;
int ScreenW,ScreenH;
Context context;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_full_news);

    this.context = getBaseContext();

    DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
    float dpWidth = displayMetrics.widthPixels;
    float dpHeight = displayMetrics.heightPixels;

    ScreenW = (int) dpWidth;
    ScreenH = (int) dpHeight;

    try {

        ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_my_content)).setText(Html.fromHtml(htmlContent, Images, null));
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        
    }
}

private Html.ImageGetter Images = new Html.ImageGetter() {

    public Drawable getDrawable(String source) {
        
        Drawable drawable = null;

        FetchImageUrl fiu = new FetchImageUrl(context,source);
        try {
            fiu.execute().get();
            drawable = fiu.GetImage();
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            drawable = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.img_news);
        }
         // to display image,center of screen
        int imgH = drawable.getIntrinsicHeight();
        int imgW = drawable.getIntrinsicWidth();
        int padding =20;
        int realWidth = ScreenW-(2*padding);
        int realHeight = imgH * realWidth/imgW;
        drawable.setBounds(padding,0,realWidth ,realHeight);
        return drawable;
    }
};
}
```

## And The FetchImageUrl class is:

```
public class FetchImageUrl extends AsyncTask<String, String, Boolean> {


String imageUrl;
Context context;
protected Drawable image;

public FetchImageUrl(Context context, String url)
{
    this.imageUrl = url;
    image = null;
    this.context = context;
}

public Drawable GetImage()
{
    return image;
}


@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    super.onPreExecute();
}

@Override
protected Boolean doInBackground(String... args) {
    try {
        InputStream input_stream = (InputStream) new URL(imageUrl).getContent();
        image = Drawable.createFromStream(input_stream, "src name");
        return true;

    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        image = null;
    }
    return false;
}


@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {

}}
```

Comment: this one working and set image center and custom height & widht         
 final float scale = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
 int dpWidthInPx  = (int) (ScreenW * scale);
 int dpHeightInPx = (int) (200 * scale);