# Android Chat application smiley

Tags: android, controls, chat

I am  developing a chat application. For smileys I have used image buttons. But the problem is that I don't know how to insert the smileys to the text control after the chat messages, similar to this:
[image]

How to do it through code? Please guide me.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5561981/how-to-display-image-in-androids-textview

Comment: @JulianFondren will it work as i wanted? I mean just as in d above image?

Comment: This one in the picture above looks like a VB.NET application...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can achieve this using ImageSpan objects. The TextViews and EditTexts use Spanned/Spannable objects to store the entered text content, not just mere java Strings. On these Spanned/Spannable objects you can define spans for sections on the text that modifies the way that those sections are shown. So you can display a text in bold, italics, etc. and you can also display images in place of certain sections.

This way you can search for a ":-)" pattern in the entered text, and slap an ImageSpan on it displaying a smiley. Check the docs  http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/style/ImageSpan.html.

Answer (score 0):

We cannot add image directly to editText and textView. for that we have to make a spannable text, and my code creates a spanned text and now you can set it to textView/editText.

```
  ImageGetter imageGetter = new ImageGetter() 
                {
                    public Drawable getDrawable(String source) {
                        Drawable d = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.e001);
                        d.setBounds(0, 0, d.getIntrinsicWidth(), d.getIntrinsicHeight());
                        return d;
                    }
                };

                Spanned cs = Html.fromHtml("<img src='" + getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.e001) + "'/>", imageGetter, null);


            yourTextView.setText(cs);
```

Comment: we cannot directly add image to textView or editText but we can do it with the help of ImageSpan, I have converted my image to spanned Text and now you can set it to textView or editText, and also i am creating a emoji keyboard it is working properly

Comment: Code-only answers are not very useful.