# Show html image and table in textview

Tags: android, html, textview

I am using a simple textview to show some html string in my android app. If I show only text with links I have no problem, but when I receive some data which contains images and tables the images are showing like obj string only and the tablet are not even shown, only the text part is showing. I know I can use webview, but i don't have so much control of the contents view and I can't customize it so much as in textview.

Is there any way that I can show tables and images in textview, while the images are saved on sd card. I don't need any methods to download them from internet and stuff like that.

Any help / suggestions / advices are appreciated!

Comment: for images look at this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5561981/how-to-display-image-in-androids-textview

and for the tables look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2116162/how-to-display-html-in-textview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. TextView is not WebView. Use the latter for more markup that elementary attributes like `<B>`, `<U>` or tags like `<A>`