# Is it possible to display a bitmap image in textview which is in listview?

Tags: android

I need to display image and text in listview using simple list item.
Is it possible to display image in a textview?

Comment: look into using custom layouts for a `listview` like [here](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/02/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text/)

Comment: if you want to display image and text in listview then make a custom layout for list_item..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a spannableString and place your image where you want in the TextView. Or you can use

```
ImageSpan is = new ImageSpan(context, resId);
text.setSpan(is, index, index + strLength, 0);
```

look here: [How to display image in Android's TextView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5561981/how-to-display-image-in-androids-textview)