# How to combine text image text inside TextView?

Tags: android

How to combine `text image text` inside TextView ?
I load text from `values/strings.xml` but how to add at the middle od text `one image icon.png` from drawable.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5562355/2001247 Check this out. This is really easy.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you put something like this in your layout:

```
<RelativeLayout android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ImageView 
            android:id="@+id/ivMiddle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/image"/>

    <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/text_left"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/ivMiddle"/>
    <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/text_right"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/ivMiddle"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Has the same effect and is a lot easier to do.

**EDIT:**

Or as ElDuderino suggested you can simply do this:

```
ImageSpan is = new ImageSpan(context, R.drawable.image);
SpannableString text = new SpannableString("Left  Right");
text.setSpan(is, 4, 4, 0);
```

Comment: Read it too quickly didn't see how you were assigning. This is correct

Comment: This is not a good idea. It's easier with this one http://stackoverflow.com/a/5562355/2001247