# How to add the images into the edit text field and how to save it as the whole edit text field as image in android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-edittext, android-button, android-image

In my app I am going to appear one screen,In that screen I am going to put the edit text field and below that edit text field I will use pick and save buttons,inside the edit text field I am going to type some text and after that where the cursor is pointing in that place I have to add the images, I would like to be taken images from the gallery using pick button and after put the images into the edit text field again I want to type some thing  after that I am going to click the save button that edit text field saved as a images into the gallery are some thing else I have searched in Google regarding this but I can not able to find any solutions please any one would help me.

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/oo0UQ.png                                  This is my edit text field i want to use my edit text field like this.

Comment: i have searched regarding this subject but i did not get any idea here after only i will going to start my task.

Comment: I am very confused can u help me yar?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to display image in Android's TextView?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5561981/how-to-display-image-in-androids-textview)

Comment: Fine, but in my project i will use edit text field.

Answer (score 0):

Try this it should work.

```
ImageSpan is = new ImageSpan(context, R.drawable.ic_displaypicture);
SpannableString text = new SpannableString("What's on your mind");
text.setSpan(is, 5, 5 + 10, 0);
```

Comment: I have tried your code but I can not get output so would you send me example code for this else send me any link.