# Embed images in <item> tag of string.xml

Tags: android, arrays

I am using `<string-array>` in my `string.xml` file. Inside this, I have multiple  tags.
Also, I am showing this text in `TextView` on a `Fragment`.

Now, in some of these item tags I want to embed images.
The issue is, I want to add these images in between the text inside `<item>` tag.

I am successfully able to add image at top, bottom or left of the `TextView` but not able to embed that in between the text.

Can anyone please let me know how to achieve this ?

Comment: From where your are fetching images???

Comment: Post code where you binding String-Array

Answer (score 0):

1/ no you can't add a reference in `string.xml`.
2/ you can do it by java using `ImageSpan` and `SpannableString` this [way](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5562355/3014036):

```
ImageSpan is = new ImageSpan(context, resId);
text.setSpan(is, index, index + strLength, 0);
```

[exemple](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12048651/3014036) :

```
ImageSpan is = new ImageSpan(context, R.drawable.arrow);
SpannableString text = new SpannableString("Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet");
text.setSpan(is, 5, 5 + 10, 0);
```