# Is there any way to add an icon to a Snackbar?

Tags: android, android-snackbar

This is my Snackbar code :

```
        Snackbar.make(viewHolder.productView, "Some Text Here ..", Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT)
                .setAction("I want be a icon here instead TEXT", new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        // Perform anything for the action selected
                    }
                })
                .show();
```

Is there anyway to add icon instead of text in `.setAction` ?

I know [google suggested not use icon in Snackbar](http://www.google.com/design/spec/components/snackbars-toasts.html#snackbars-toasts-usage), but I want to use it.

Answer (score 70, accepted):

ImageSpan may not look right with longer text (multiple lines). Instead, use a left compound drawable (same as `android:drawableLeft`).

```
Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar.make(layout, R.string.test, Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG);
View snackbarLayout = snackbar.getView();
TextView textView = (TextView)snackbarLayout.findViewById(android.support.design.R.id.snackbar_text);
textView.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(R.drawable.white_checkbox, 0, 0, 0);
textView.setCompoundDrawablePadding(getResources().getDimensionPixelOffset(R.dimen.snackbar_icon_padding));
snackbar.show();
```

If you are using the AndroidX Material library, replace `android.support.design.R.id.snackbar_text` with `com.google.android.material.R.id.snackbar_text`.

Comment: I do like this method better than accepted, BUT will google decide to make `id/snackbar_text` be a custom view which doesn't support compound drawables, this method may just fail silently

Comment: setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds() method API 17+

Comment: You are looking at `setCompoundDrawablesRelativeWithIntrinsicBounds` instead of  `setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds`

Comment: how to set gravity to right of close button of textview.

Comment: @Max Ch, good point. That's why you better place code `textView.setCompoundDrawables...` into the following `if`clause: `if(textView != null && textView instanceof TextView) {//add here drawable and padding} snackbar.show()`;

Comment: If using Material library, use `com.google.android.material.R.id.snackbar_text` to find the TextView

Answer (score 21):

Have you heard of ImageSpan? It may help you you to achieve your goal!
See below code:

```
SpannableStringBuilder builder = new SpannableStringBuilder();
builder.append("My message ").append(" ");
builder.setSpan(new ImageSpan(MainActivity.this, R.drawable.ic_launcher), builder.length() - 1, builder.length(), 0);
builder.append(" next message");
Snackbar.make(parent view, builder, Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();]
```

Dont use big icons as they will not maintain gravity.

Ref:[How to display image in Android's TextView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5561981/how-to-display-image-in-androids-textview)

Hope it helped.

Answer (score 6):

If you are using Kotlin then you can also use this extension function (for com.google.android.material):

```
import com.google.android.material.snackbar.Snackbar
import android.widget.TextView
import android.graphics.PorterDuff
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable
import androidx.annotation.ColorInt

fun Snackbar.setIcon(drawable: Drawable, @ColorInt colorTint: Int): Snackbar {
    return this.apply {
        setAction(" ") {}
        val textView = view.findViewById<TextView>(com.google.android.material.R.id.snackbar_action)
        textView.text = ""

        drawable.setTint(colorTint)
        drawable.setTintMode(PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP)
        textView.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(drawable, null, null, null)
    }
}
```

Use it with your snackbar like this:

```
Snackbar.make(view, "Hey there!", Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT)
        .setIcon(
            getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_launcher)!!,
            resources.getColor(android.R.color.white, theme)
        )
        .show()
```

Comment: Any way to set the drawable to left of text?

Comment: Use `snackbar_text` instead of `snackbar_action`

Answer (score 5):

Easy 2020 solution, if you want JUST the icon without action text:

```
Snackbar.make(anchor, message, Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE).apply {

  setAction(" ") { // onClick event }
  // the " " is just so android can create the view, otherwise it won't, it will be cleared later

  val textView = view.findViewById<TextView>(com.google.android.material.R.id.snackbar_action)
  textView.text = "" // clear the text to keep only the icon
  textView.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(R.drawable.ic_whatever, 0, 0, 0)

  show()
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You also can add views to SnackbarContentLayout

Kotlin code:

```
val snackbar = Snackbar.make(....
val textView = snackbar.view.findViewById(R.id.snackbar_action) as TextView
textView.isAllCaps = false
val imgClose = ImageView(context)
imgClose.scaleType = ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_INSIDE
val layImageParams = ViewGroup.LayoutParams(WRAP_CONTENT, MATCH_PARENT)
imgClose.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_close)
(textView.parent as SnackbarContentLayout).addView(imgClose, layImageParams)
imgClose.setOnClickListener { snackbar.dismiss() }
snackbar.show()
```

Answer (score 3):

This is all you can change of a `Snackbar`:

```
Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar
  .make(parentLayout, R.string.snackbar_text, Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
  .setAction(R.string.snackbar_action, myOnClickListener);
snackbar.setActionTextColor(Color.CYAN);
View snackbarView = snackbar.getView();
snackbarView.setBackgroundColor(Color.YELLOW);//change Snackbar's background color;
TextView textView = (TextView)snackbarView .findViewById(android.support.design.R.id.snackbar_text);
textView.setTextColor(Color.BLUE);//change Snackbar's text color;
snackbar.show(); // Don’t forget to show!
```

Unfortunately, we still can't customize contents of a `Snackbar` by far like we do to `Toast`. In the future? I don't know.

Comment: Thank you , but when i used textView.setBackground(R.drawable.icon); it filled all of the text view ..  I used @Harry 's answer and it workes :D , Tnx again <3

Answer (score 2):

Suppose you want to add an icon to the left of a snackbar. The following code helps you achieve this:

```
SpannableStringBuilder builderTextLeft = new SpannableStringBuilder();
builderTextLeft.append(" ");
builderTextLeft.setSpan(new ImageSpan(context, R.drawable.ic_vector), 0, 1, 0);
Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar.make(parentLayout, builderTextLeft, Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG);
snackbar.show();
```

In the above code I have added an info icon to the left of the snackbar.

If you want to add an icon to the right of a snackbar, you need to do the following:

```
SpannableStringBuilder buildetTextRight = new SpannableStringBuilder();
buildetTextRight.append(" ");
buildetTextRight.setSpan(new ImageSpan(context, R.drawable.ic_close),
                buildetTextRight.length()-1, buildetTextRight.length(), 0);
```

In the above code, I have added a close icon to the right of the snackbar.