# Image added inside of EditText like adding an image to WordPad

Tags: android, android-layout, android-edittext

I have an app working with an EditText that is used as a Notes feature for my app. Works fine writing saving and updating etc. That is all being done using the SQLite database.

What I want to do is let the user add a image to the notes like one would add an image to let's say WordPad. Can that be possible using the edit text or will I have to either make it an actual File and have the image broken into a bitmap as added to the file to be read and recreated into the image?

Thanks for reading this question. Long winded alright but if any info can be given I can work towards doing it myself :)

Comment: try this:  [http://stackoverflow.com/a/5562355/1532687](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5562355/1532687)

Comment: Thanks for the fast response Robert! I will try using it and get back to you :).